# PHP7 create session file, but cannot write content

Tags: php, session, php-7

Since updating from PHP 5.7 to PHP 7.0.8, I experience the following problem:

`Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/media/path/system/session) in Unknown on line 0`

Actually, PHP creates a new session file, but seems not to write into it. Obviously, the file permissions do not cause the problem, because the session path has x777 and the following test code (run before `session_start()`) works perfectly:

```
$testfile = session_save_path().'/somefile';
file_put_contents($testfile, 'TEST');
```

I did the update after updating my system fro Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, so I cannot eliminate the possibility that any of the updated packages causes the problem. However, I have no more idea how to track down this issue...

- If I do not set the session.save_path via `session_save_path()`, the default path `/var/lib/php/sessions` works well. And `/tmp/` works fine, as well.
- Notably, my preferred path is located on an verycrypt-ecrypted FAT32 partition (mounted with `umask=0000`), so PHP files from the partition can run.

Any ideas what causes the issue or how to solve it?

Comment: I have had similar notifications on line zero as yours (PHP5.6), and found it to be the drive (account) was exceeding its allotted disk space at time of process. Not sure if this would or could be an issue for your situation?

Comment: More than 500 MB of free space should be sufficient for a session. `disc_free_space()` also reports the amount of available memory. I wonder if PHP's session management uses some other function that reports a wrong value for FAT32 unter Linux?!

Comment: I should clarify what was happening with me was that the account on the server was exceeding its disk usage... but it seems this is not your issue.